# iPhone 5 support with base SDK iOS5.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios6, iphone-5

Is is possible to submit the app with base SDK iOS5.1 and with Default-568h@2x.png, so that application will not leave an extra black space?

Our normal application is working fine on iPhone5 leaving a black space from top and bottom, but if we just include "Default-568h@2x.png", will it work fine (the view displayed in complete area of iPhone5)?

There are lots of dependencies to support iOS6, so is it possible to submit the app with "Default-568h@2x.png" and base SDK iOS5.1?

Comment: I would try running the app on an iOS 5 device, or if you don't have one available, try downloading the iOS 5 simulator inside Xcode.

Comment: I would also add to the question required screenshots resolution for AppStore, that's now not clear as well.

Comment: The application is running fine both on device as well as simulator.
My main concern is whether Apple will approve the application or not as I am using base SDK 5.1 instead of iOS6.0

Comment: I have a problem with iOS 6 as well. but it took me 3 days to make the coordinate compatible with 4 inch display. hope apple wont reject apps that is based on 5.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is impossible to submit the iPhone 5 full screen app which is built with Xcode 4.4.1 and iOS 5.1 SDK. I did the same thing to support both old devices of armv6/iOS 3.x and iPhone 5. But I got this reject message from itunesconnect. I think it is the new policy of App Store.

"Invalid Launch Image - You app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later."

Comment: It looks like this is a new change within the last 2 days or so, too. I uploaded a build on Thurs 27th Sept, which worked just fine on an iPhone 5 after adding just the launch image - and it got as far as 'waiting for review'.  But I found a nasty bug, and rejected that binary. When uploading a fixed build today (29th), I ran into the 'Invalid Launch Image' rejection (near-instant automated rejection after the upload completes) Argh! Updating the SDK isn't an option for people using some middleware/SDKs, we've just got to sit around and wait for the middleware providers to update to SDK 6.0.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, if we are building our app with Xcode 4.4.1 and iOS 5.1 SDK.

Answer (score 2):

just edit the size of Default-568h@2x.png with the same one of Default@x2.png splash screens, don't rename it, adjust only it size, it's how it worked for me, seems the binary does gets faked, my app it's waiting for the review don't know yet if will be approved.

Comment: Default@2x.png is used for iPhone retina display, don't know how it behave if the size is greater than 640x960. People saying if you support iPhone5 without supporting iOS6, the application might behave weird.

Comment: This doesn't work. Runs OK on the phone, but submissions still get rejected with the 'Invalid Launch Image' message.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any policy from Apple to forbid developers to submit apps based on SDK 5.1.  My understanding is that if you develop on SDK 5.1 you should also test your app on iOS 6.

Having said that, iOS 6 SDK provides good features to help developers manage the layout, and Apple surely wants the developers to use the latest.

Comment: And what about the iPhone 5 then?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that issue the following way: I'm using iOS SDK 5.1 and Xcode 4.4.1.
Now I've added simply the Default-568h@2x.png to the upper folder of my App in Xcode but not with Xcode 4.5.1.

Then I've built the App through iPhone 5.1 Simulator and finally I've quit the Simulator.
Then go to ../users/myNameUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/... search for your App and Copy the complete folder (e.g. F83221EA-1HB4-4947-9DH4-43D8QZ3FFEA3).
Then go to ../users/myNameUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/ and paste in the copied folder from the 5.1 Simulator.

Finally open your Applications folder go to your Xcode App (4.5.1) then right click and show package content: Go to ../contents/applications/ and double click "iPhone Simulator.app".
Now you are running the new iPhone Simulator with your iOS SDK 5.1 App. Great job? Now you can change the hardware of the simulator to the new iPhone Retina-4-inch.
And you can see how your App will look like on the new iPhone 5.

I've sent my new App version by that way for review - well see if it'll get through.
(Sent with: Xcode 4.4.1 and iPhone 5 support like described on top)

By the way it could be interesting to run Apps from Xcode 4.4 on real iOS 6 Device?
How to do that: [Use iOS 6 device for testing with Xcode 4.4 and iOS 5 SDK](http://www.jonathanhogervorst.com/post/27550170932/use-ios-6-device-for-testing-with-xcode-4-4-and-ios-5)

Comment: What you do in your simulator and simulator package contents has little to do with submitting the app, since that is an iOS package build complete separate from your simulator.

Comment: @Jelle, yes you're right. But I think it's unimportant for everyone now, because now we have a later official version of XCode. ;) And I think everyone should use the latest official version, to support Apples latest Devices...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid "Invalid Launch Image" problem on submitting app with iPhone 5 launch image using XCode 4.4.1, please following these steps:

1. Archive your App under XCode 4.5
2. Open Organizer, show your App folder in Finder, enter your App’s Products/Applications folder, copy Info.plist and archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent to your home folder.
3. Open your Info.plist (~/Info.plist) using XCode, and modify MinimumOSVersion from 4.3 to 4.0
4. Close XCode 4.5 and open XCode 4.4.1, open your App project and open your Target’s “Build Phrases” tab, add a Run Script, with shell “/bin/sh” and “cp -f ~/Info.plist ~/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent “${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.app”
5. Re-archive your App, and it should pass App Store’s rule checker and in “Waiting for review” soon.

The app I submitted late October got online in early November. Someone said he used XCode 4.3.2 to submit app in the same way. It should be working for XCode 4.*

For more information, please also [read this blog article](http://dev.zhourenjian.com/blog/2012/11/11/submit-to-app-store-using-xcode-4-4-1-with-iphone-5-supported.html).

Answer (score 0):

I submitted by mid-feb my binary compiled  on Xcode3.2.6 and only had the Default.png, my App got rejected due to a bug related to the 4" screens, some stupid sizing junk, fixed it and tested on Xcode4.6/SDK6.1 which requires that 568h@2x.png file, I added that image to my set , still compiled it on 3.2.6 and submitted my fix and it got automatically rejected with the same msg as here.

Then I just pulled that 568 file out and resubmitted hoping that since it went thru about 2 weeks ago it'd get past again, I triple checked my code on sdk6.1, recompiled/ressubmitted and got the same rejection so it seems like they are enforcing that min Xcode version NOW.

BUT .... guess what? I cleaned everything and twice and rebuilt & decided to give it a last shot, resubmitted and it passed!!! I'm on waiting 4 review now.